# gradient text on top of colored background?

Tags: html, tooltip

i'm wanting my link titles to have a gradient text. currently, when i change the tooltip to be the gradient text, the gradient ends up working fine, but the background is transparent.

i want to have a colored background so you can actually see the text. i understand that the way the gradient is working is by using a gradient background and then cutting out the text to show it, but i think there has to be a way to overlay the whole text over a background.

i'm not sure exactly how to edit tooltips very well, i'm using someone's code and editing it. i'm attaching a picture of what i'm basically trying to do. (the photo is edited because i haven't been able to actually make this happen lmao).

inside of my tooltip, i want to have the gradient text, the color background behind the gradient text, and a border.

there's a picture of what i currently see[image: what i currently see],

there's a picture of what happens when i change the text to gradient [image: what happens when i change the text to gradient],

and there's a picture of what i'm trying to get to [image: what i'm trying to get to].

thank you all in advance for any help you can give me!

```css
    #s-m-t-tooltip {
        font-family:"georgia";
        letter-spacing:1px;
        text-transform:uppercase;
        text-align:center;
        position:absolute;
        padding:0px 5px 0px 5px;
        margin-top:30px;
        border:1px solid black;
        z-index:9999;
    }
```

*edit - added snippet of tooltip code (i'm new at this site so i'm not sure if this will post the code correctly)*

Comment: Please edit your question and include the relevant bits of your code. See [mre].

Comment: @lupz i added the code snippet of the tooltip, let me know if that's helpful! i wasn't sure what else to include in the code snippet

Comment: I was writing an answer pointing out that "no, this is absolutely not possible" but then I somehow ended up with this result: https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/wr10zpge/ and https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/wr10zpge/1/; unfortunately I don't know why it works.  It seems to have issues though if you experiment with variably transparent colours in the 'furthest'/'deepest' `background-image`.

Comment: @DavidThomas: here's why it works: [Multiple Backgrounds](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Backgrounds_and_Borders/Using_multiple_backgrounds)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option, embed the tooltip in another `div` to manage the background:

---

###### Updated 3-Aug-22 per @DavidThomas

```css
.col {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 250px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.outer {
  position: relative;
}

.note {
  font-size: 8pt;
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 1.2em;
}

.pos {
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  left: 15px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.inner {
  background-color: white;
}

.kpb {
  font-family: "georgia";
  font-size: 14pt;
  font-weight: bold;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0px 5px;
}

.kpb::before {
  content: "Kiwi polar bear";
}

.s-m-t-tooltip {
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#eee, #333);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}

.dave-thomas {
  color: transparent;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, red, orange, yellow, lime, indigo, blue, violet), linear-gradient(to bottom, #FFF, #FFF);
  -webkit-background-clip: text, border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="col">
  <span class="note">Single BG overlaid on white div</span><br>
  <div class="outer">
    <image src="https://picsum.photos/250/200" />
    <div class="pos inner">
      <div class="kpb s-m-t-tooltip"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col">
  <span class="note">Per Dave Thomas: Two background layers with paired clipping levels (order matters)</span><br>
  <div class="outer">
    <image src="https://picsum.photos/250/200" />
    <div class="pos kpb dave-thomas"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```